# Python 3 support in ROS Lunar Loggerhead?

Tags: python, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do we finally get Python 3 support in Lunar Loggerhead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261904/python-3-support-in-ros-lunar-loggerhead?/) by [John Nagle](https://answers.ros.org/users/2519/john-nagle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I interpret [REP-003](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) correctly, the [Lunar section](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019) seems to say: Python 2.7 is default, but it'd be nice if your code works on 3.5 as well:

> Python 3.5 not required, but testing against it is recommended

No hard guarantees apparently.

I know there has been quite some work getting all the core packages Python 3 compatible though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0